# Clean with progress bar

Tags: batch-file

I need to wipe a disk on my PC, so I have made a batch file that basically creates a partition, and cleans it using command `DISKPART clean all`. I want to output a progress bar of that somehow, does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `DISKPART` doesn't provide any incremental output that could be used to provide a progress bar of any sort.

Before starting the operation you may simply want to warn the user with an Echo statement:

```
echo Cleaning disk. This may take a bit. Please wait...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to clean your pc i don't see the need of a progress bar. If you for some reason want to have a script with progress bar you could fragment the disk in several partitions and clean them in a loop. After each partition you can update the progress bar.